# Firebase exception when updating email: You must enable this service in the console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to build an "edit account" page in Unity using firebase, and for some reason everything works just fine except when I try to call user.UpdateEmailAsync(email). It returns this exception: Firebase.FirebaseException: This operation is not allowed. You must enable this service in the console.

[image: Email/Password sign-in method enabled in firebase console]
Email/Password sign-in method enabled in firebase console

I do have email/password authentication enabled in the firebase console, so I'm not sure how to solve this exception
Note: I don't get this exception when signing up users, only when i attempt to update their email.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.